# WD external hard drive some folders can not be viewed due to a possible virus?

Tags: permissions, external-hard-drive, virus, cmd.exe, malware

Now I am using a windows 8.1, Samsung laptop, with WD Elements 1tb. The problem is one day some folders in my external drive decided to not show up. I figured it might be due to some virus affecting the permissions, thought some how my user permissions don't allow to view some folders and files, etc. but although I gave all the permissions to the current user it doesn't seem to be working.
I tried to use command prompt `attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*` this didn't work either. After this i thought maybe i actually deleted stuff without knowing it because cmd should have worked if the files and folders were hidden. Then I scanned the folder with avast antivirus and saw the folder names and files that are supposed to be deleted. Now, I have absolutely no idea what to do, I don't know how avast scan procedure captures something that cdm doesn't show... I think I'll stop using windows after this, everything is just so secretive, and it is such a pain to correct stuff.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking... if you just run`cmd` as administrator and go to that drive and do a `dir /a` are the files or directories there? Why do think this is a virus or malware issue, did your security package indicate an issue?

Comment: What the person above said, plus possibly an obvious question: Are the paths that showed up in the Avast scan what you would expect normally? Meaning, is it possible that you're seeing scan results from the recycle bin or inside of a folder that they were moved to accidentally?

Comment: I run cmd as administrator and went to that drive and to the specific folder that miss two subfolders, and did dir /a, normally I need to see three folders but now i only see one, besides the "." and ".." . As for the scan results no, I made a folder scan on the folder which supposed to had three subfolders. In the antivirus scan I saw the name of the two missing with their contents

Comment: @KaanE. That doesn't make any sense, if you ran `cmd` as Administrator and did a `dir /a` and the files are not there, they are not there. I do not see how Avast could see them. If this was me, at this point I would boot a live Linux environment and look at the drive, especially if you think there is even a potential of anykind of virus or malware doing something, you should be able to access the file (if they exists) and copy them off.

Comment: I have checked to see if I was mistaken at anything. I still don't have anything in cmd as administrator, but I noticed that the scans that Avast made have a different path than the folder I am scanning. In a C:\A\B\X\D schema, I scan X, but the path that avast shows for the file is C:\A\B\D skipping the folder name that marks the beginning of the scanning procedure (English is my second language, sorry for weird formulations), so to answer @BrianC avast doesn't show regular paths, sorry for the early response

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved once I did a defrag and checkdisk, and repair to the external drive and changed the access permissions to all the folders in the drive. Now bye bye windows in a week,
Thank you all for the help
Best Regards